# Sampling points on raster layer with specific patterns

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I new on using R with spatial data and I don't understand how to fix my issue.

My goal is to test differents pattern to make soil sample for quantifying soil organic carbon. I have a raster layer which represent the carbon stock with a grid of 1m*1m.
On this raster I want to randomly chose 20 points across the diagonal of the plot (which is rectangular). And I want each point separated by 20 meters.
Then I would like to repeat this operation a lot of times and each times I would like that each points move à litle bit in a certain range around the diagonal.

I'm trying with raster::select function but I don't understand the way it's work.

If you have any help to give me or just some good R package to do this I woul apreciate a lot !

Thank you,

Antoine

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It's much easier for us to help you if you can show us some code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what are the dimensions of your raster?